# How to show multiple images in a flipview winrt?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I wanted to create a flipview but with multiple images showing simultaneously.
Example:
[image]

Like in the case of windows store which has like a scrollviewer to the flipview.
How can I achieve something like this?

Currently I'm only able to achieve something where I can have one image as the source at any given instance.

Edit: My code

```
<FlipView x:Name="PCFlipview" Background="Black"
                Height="350" Width="620"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PcScreens}"
                SelectionChanged="FlipView1_SelectionChanged"
                Style="{StaticResource FlipViewStyle1}">
      <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Grid >
                  <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Uniform" />
              </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
      </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
  </FlipView>
```

Comment: Did you try using any repeater as `ItemTemplate` of `FlipView`?

Comment: I have added the code!

Comment: Since you want multiple items, use a repeater instead of a single image.

Comment: Could you give an example? Cause I really wouldn't be knowing how many images are bound to the flipview

Comment: ? I thought what you want is to display 3 images in each `FlipViewItem`.

Comment: No the number of images could be any in the flipview there is a horizontal slider. You can check out the windows 10 store app for reference

Comment: No, Flip views work best for collections of up to 25 or so items. What you say is showing one Image in each item, but your posted picture is showing 3 images in one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show multiple images in one `FlipViewItem`, you can use the [FlipView.ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) for example like this:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding image1}" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Image Source="{Binding image2}" Grid.Column="2" />
                <Image Source="{Binding image3}" Grid.Column="4" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyFlipViewItem> items;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<MyFlipViewItem>();
        flipView.ItemsSource = items;            
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        items.Clear();
        items.Add(new MyFlipViewItem { image1 = "Assets/1.jpeg", image2 = "Assets/2.jpeg", image3 = "Assets/3.png" });
        items.Add(new MyFlipViewItem { image1 = "Assets/1.jpeg", image2 = "Assets/2.jpeg", image3 = "Assets/3.png" });
        items.Add(new MyFlipViewItem { image1 = "Assets/1.jpeg", image2 = "Assets/2.jpeg", image3 = "Assets/3.png" });
        items.Add(new MyFlipViewItem { image1 = "Assets/1.jpeg", image2 = "Assets/2.jpeg", image3 = "Assets/3.png" });
        items.Add(new MyFlipViewItem { image1 = "Assets/1.jpeg", image2 = "Assets/2.jpeg", image3 = "Assets/3.png" });
    }
}

public class MyFlipViewItem
{
    public string image1 { get; set; }
    public string image2 { get; set; }
    public string image3 { get; set; }
}
```

Additions:
But a default `FlipView` has no round points at the bottom of it, we need to [Add a context indicator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview#adding-a-context-indicator) manually.

There is a opensource package [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto) you can use to create this indicator, it can be downloaded from the NuGet of VS2015 and used like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MultipleImageInOneFlipView.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MultipleImageInOneFlipView"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:callisto="using:Callisto.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
      ....
      <callisto:FlipViewIndicator Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FlipView="{Binding ElementName=flipView}">
      </callisto:FlipViewIndicator>
      ...
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

But the style of this indicator is like this:
[image]

So we can create a indicator using `ListBox` for example like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="indicator" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=flipView, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="15" Height="15" Margin="10,0" 
                     Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Foreground}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```cs
indicator.ItemsSource = items;
```

As you've seen, I modified the style template of `ListBoxItem`, the default template can be added to the xaml code like this:
[image]

And I modify the style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            ...
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                        </Style>
                        <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Fill="Transparent" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource BodyContentPresenterStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here I wrote a [demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/Pivot-FlipView-and-FlipView-indicator) to reproduce the layout in your picture, you may also take a look at it.

**Update**

I've update my project, here is the rendering image of my demo:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. But what I need is something similar but one more condition is that there can be many images visible at one instance if you see the store app for reference.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith, I'm confused now, what you want to do is not like the picture you posted? Or, you just want to know how to add items to flipview?

Comment: Check out this video https://youtu.be/F39xV6zfAXU, that is something I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @AbsoluteSith, the app in you video has a pivot with two items: mobile and pc. In the "mobile" item, the flipview has two items, each items display 3 images (I've done the same in my old answer). In the "pc" item, the flipview has 5 items, each item show 1 iamge (This is done in my update project). Please check the update in my answer and just download my demo to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want multiple items, use a repeater as `FlipView`'s `ItemTemplate`. Here's an example:

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

`ItemsControl` don't have `ScrollViewer` so you need to explicitly use it since you don't know how many items there will be. However, you can use `ListView` or `GridView` as well as per your requirements.

Comment: Yeah I guess one has to use a gridview in that case

Comment: Yes, I'd go with `GridView` too.

Comment: You'd need to make some changes. Basic concept is to have collection inside another collection. Your `ViewModel` property might looks like `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> NestedCollection`. I can make you a sample if you want.